# ListView carrega pela chamada do construtor mas não pelo botão

Tags: listview, xamarin-forms

Tenho um listview no meu app e criei na minha ViewModel uma metodo CarregarListView();

Quando eu chamo ele pelo construtor da minha ViewModel, uma lista ObservableCollection é carregada e é dado o binding na minha view.

Quando chamo o método CarregarListView() por um command de um botão o método CarregarListView() é chamado e a lista é carregada, mas não dá binding na minha view.

Alguém sabe o motivo disso?

Esse é meu listView

```
    <ListView Grid.Row="2"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ListaIntervalos }" 
                      HasUnevenRows="true">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid> 
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding De}"  FontSize="20" VerticalOptions="Start" TextColor="Black"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Ate}"  FontSize="20" VerticalOptions="Start" TextColor="Black"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

E na minha View Model esta assim

```
    public ObservableCollection<Intervalo> ListaIntervalos { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<Intervalo>();

    //Construtor
    public VMBuscarSalto()
    {
        // Aqui funciona
        this.CarregaIntervalos();
    }

    public Command BuscaSaltosCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() => ExecuteBuscaSaltosCommand());
        }
    }

    private void ExecuteBuscaSaltosCommand()
    { 
        // Aqui a lista é carregada mas não dá o bind no listview
        this.CarregaIntervalos();
    }
```

Comment: Teria [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder ser analisado ?

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela atenção.
Eu complementei meu post com o código.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema relatado não tenha sido algo que eu tenha feito errado, e sim deva ser bug no componente ListView da Xamarin, que cá entre nós, esta cheio de falhas com relação ao uso de suas funcionalidades utilizando MVVM.

Resolvi meu problema utilizando o Code Behind, que é simplesmente carregando a propriedade  ItemsSource do listview em XAML

```
    <ListView Grid.Row="2"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  
                      x:Name="GridDeIntervalos">
```

e no code behind

```
     List<Intervalo> listIntervaloModel = new List<Intervalo>();


            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                listIntervaloModel.Add(new Intervalo
                {
                    De = "teste " + i,
                    Ate = "teste " + i
                });
            }

            GridDeIntervalos.ItemsSource = listIntervaloModel;
```